# Android Interface Design

Tags: android

I am new to android. 
I'am creating an ToDoTask application in android. 
I have given all the functionalities. But now I want to make my application look better so I need to design this application so that it looks more attractive. Can you please suggest me any site which is about designing user interface for android.

Answer (score 2):

I think first you should go through design guidelines of andriod

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/index.html

And then have look at http://www.androiduipatterns.com/p/android-ui-pattern-collection.html

Answer (score 1):

I think the book [Android User Interface Development: Beginner's Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1849514488)  by Jason Morris will be helpful.